# How to set the listener on a dynamic node? Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to get all the players on the current coordinate, which changes with each turn. The problem is that the onChildAdded, onChildRemoved method works more than necessary, if I return to the coordinates that I already had. What am I doing wrong?

base structure

[image]

When the user goes north, the onNorth method is performed, in which old coordinates are deleted and add new ones in the nodes "users / uid / location and locations"

```
public void onNorth(View view) {
    Map<String, Object> update = new HashMap<>();
    update.put("locations/"+ns+"/"+we+"/"+userId, null);
    ++ns;
    update.put("users/" + userId + "/location/ns", ns);
    update.put("locations/"+ns+"/"+we+"/"+userId, new User("Bot"));

    mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().updateChildren(update);
}
```

I set the listener to get the current coordinates ("users/userId/location").

```
mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
mReferenceLocation = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference("users/" + userId + "/location");

if (mValueEventListener == null) {
mValueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Location location = dataSnapshot.getValue(Location.class);
        ns = location.getNs();
        we = location.getWe();

        //Listener on current position(locations)
        setListenerForCurrentLocation(ns,we);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
};

mReferenceLocation.addValueEventListener(mValueEventListener);}
```

I set the listener for to get all users in the current location

```
mReferenceLocations = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference("locations/" + ns+"/"+we);
public void setListenerForCurrentLocation(long ns, long we){
    mChildEventListenerLocations = new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        Log.e("onChildAdded", dataSnapshot.getKey());
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s){
            Log.e("onChildChanged", dataSnapshot.getKey());
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Log.e("onChildRemoved", dataSnapshot.getKey());
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        Log.e("onChildMoved", dataSnapshot.getKey());
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }
};
mReferenceLocations.addChildEventListener(mChildEventListenerLocations);
}
```